# Método postLink não existe na versão 2.4.4 do CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, post

Estou a tentar utilizar o método postLink para apagar imagens, utilizando o nome destas. No entanto o Cake dá-me um erro dizendo :**Warning (512): Method HtmlHelper::postLink does not exist [CORE\Cake\View\Helper.php, line 192]**. Mas depois de ver os changelogs do Cake, e a própria documentação do CakePHP 2.4.4, que estou a usar, não há nada que indique que este método tenha desaparecido. Como se resolve este problema?

**Código**

```
    echo $this->Html->postLink('gallery/'.$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'], array('controller' =>'Gallery', 'action'=>'admin_del_image'),array(), "tem a certeza que quer apagar esta Fotografia?");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade você está utilizando o *helper* errado. O correto é o `FormHelper` e não o `HtmlHelper`.

Como você pode ver na **[API](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-FormHelper.html#_postLink)** e na **[documentação](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper%3a%3apostLink)**.